# how can I get access to a document in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

in my project im trying to get the id of the video and then open the video in my video but im struggling in 3 points

1. how can I can save real id into firebase?
   this is how im doing it right know

```
uploadVideo() async {
    setState(() {
      isuploading = true;
    });
    try {
      var firebaseuseruid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
      DocumentSnapshot userdoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('meinprofilsettings')
          .doc(firebaseuseruid)
          .get();
      var alldocs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').get();
      int length = alldocs.docs.length;
      String videourl = await uploadvideotostorage("Video $length");
      String previewimage = await uploadimagetostorage("Video $length");
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc("Video $length").set({
        'username': userdoc.data()['username'],
        'uid': firebaseuseruid,
        'profilepic': userdoc.data()['url'],
        'id':"Video $length",
        'likes': [],
        'commentcount': 0,
        'sharecount': 0,
        'hashtag1': hashtagcontroller.text,
        'hashtag2': hashtagcontroller2.text,
        'hashtag3': hashtagcontroller3.text,
        'videourl': videourl,
        'previewimage': previewimage,
        'ratings': [],

      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is the real id of the video instead of "Video $length"
2. how can I get access to the id when its created like how can I call it ? ?
3. How can I create a new collection with this id and then like saving some data but like this
new collection=> videoed => new field with some data , new field with some data

Heres how I upload it
the picture is for preview picture

```
getpreviewimage() async {
    final previewimage = await flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnailWithFile(
      widget.videopath_asstring,
    );
    return previewimage;
  }

  compressvideo() async {
    if (widget.imageSource == ImageSource.gallery) {
      return widget.videofile;
    } else {
      final compressvideo = await flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
          widget.videopath_asstring,
          quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality);
      return File(compressvideo.path);
    }
  }

  uploadvideotostorage(String id) async {
    final video = await allvideos.child(id).putFile(await compressvideo());
    String url = await video.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }

  uploadimagetostorage(String id) async {
    final video = await allimages.child(id).putFile(await getpreviewimage());
    String url = await video.ref.getDownloadURL();
    id=url;
    return url;
  }
```

Comment: Please post this function `uploadvideotostorage`, if you are uploading to firebase storage, you can call `getDownloadUrl()` after upload is done, but still, we need to see those functions please.

Comment: Please check code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, change them to look like this:

```
 Future<String> uploadvideotostorage(String id) async {
    final video = await allvideos.child(id).putFile(await compressvideo());
    String url = await video.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }

 Future<String> uploadimagetostorage(String id) async {
    final video = await allimages.child(id).putFile(await getpreviewimage());
    String url = await video.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

- and this:

  ```
  String videourl = await uploadvideotostorage(firebaseuseruid);
  ```

`'id':videourl,`

This is assuming that `compressvideo()` is working correctly.

Comment: its loading and loading and loading and not ending . Also I wanna create a random video id not making it equal user uid

Comment: please provide more information regarding how you are getting the videos and how is compress video working, and your json map isn't very clear. Any help you offer, would make the odds of getting it to work higher.

Comment: The video is picking from user, he can uploads it from camera or from gallery. I update my code so you can see the infos that you asking for . uploading video works perfectly . But the name of a video is Video0,Video1,Video3 and so on when im deleting Video1, firebase or my methods start struggling and thats the problem because of that I want a normal id  butnnot equal to user id because when user uploads a video all videos will be have the same id and how I should call a specific video id .Hope thats enough information if not leave comment

Comment: And the id I need to call from another page when im returning this page . Example I wanna open that video so ihave a one press button in one page where the video picture is shown and then I wanna open that video on click